# apt will not install any packages from newly added repos

Tags: debian

I'm using a fresh install of Debian 9 (Stretch) in a VM with `arm64` arch.
I wanted to install Docker and .NET Core, I followed their instructions to add repositories (which worked fine on different installations).
When I execute `sudo apt update`, everything looks fine, it lists new repositories and can connect to them.
But when I try to install `docker-ce`, or `dotnet-sdk`, `apt` says the packages can't be found.

How can I diagnose what is wrong with my repo setup?

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
deb [arch=armhf] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable

$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft-prod.list
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch main

$ sudo apt update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable InRelease
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable-updates InRelease [91.0 kB]
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stable Release
Get:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch InRelease [39.1 kB]
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod stretch InRelease
Fetched 130 kB in 8s (15.6 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-2.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.1
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.1'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.1'

$ sudo apt install docker-ce
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce
```

Comment: @Kiwy updated question

Comment: what's the output of "apt search dotnet" ?

Comment: @VladimirPerevalov see now you have your answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Docker CE, you need to adjust your repository definition to match your system’s architecture:

```
deb [arch=arm64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian stretch stable
```

Microsoft don’t provide .NET Core packages for your architecture, only for `amd64`; you’ll need to [download the binary tarballs](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) and follow the instructions to install them manually.

Comment: Thanks! I could install docker and now understand the problem with dotnet

Answer (score 4):

Your repositories don't support[[1]](https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/9/prod/dists/stretch/main/) your architecture a**rm**64, only a**md**64, find better repositories.

Comment: Actually your comment have given me the answer. Apt search output shows package architecture and i've noticed the difference. Thanks